# Unable to retrieve location in swift 9.2 simulator

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

Unable to retrieve location using Swift ios 9.2. Attaching a screenshot of the code. Please check and help. 
[image]

Comment: You have to start your locationManager in order to ask for authorization, and can you show us the code inside your `didUpdateLocation` ?

Comment: Hello, I didn't import the CoreLocation library into my project. How do I do that?

Comment: You already did with `import CoreLocation` at the beginning of your file don't you ?

Comment: well yes. Do you mean to say that I have to override the function didUpdateLocation that comes with the CoreLocation library?

Comment: Yes you should, and try to print the location in this method, it's called everytime a new position is found, so if you want to print it, just implement it:     
`func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let lastLoc = locations.last {
        // Print it if you want
        }
    }`

Comment: Tried that, didn't help. I see that the func itself is not called, since the statement print("test log") itself is not executed while running .

Comment: What is odd is, I don't see a pop up message request access to Location services when the app is opened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111245/discussion-between-manalalz-and-adf-mobile-developer).

Answer (score 0):

*If this works on an actual device this may be the problem*

Sometimes the simulator is a little buggy.  A lot of the time I find myself having to do this:

Select your simulator, Look for the Debug menu up top, open the Location tab

- if your Location is not "None", turn it off now and then open up Debug menu again, and reselect whatever location was selected
- otherwise, select the location you want.  Toggle it to None and then back sometimes when having issues

Comment: I already tried that several times. It didn't work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Then probably what you need is to implement CLLocationManagerDelegate to give to your locationManager, from which you may information such as

locationManager(manager:, didUpdateLocations: )

will be sent, asynchronously.  When you turn on your locationManager, it takes a little while to get information about where you are or even what the authorization status is of the manager.